# TClientDataset.ApplyUpdates fails with 'SQL not supported' when using SQLDirect components

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, tclientdataset

After updating from DelphiXE2 to Delphi Seattle 10 Update 1 we have issues executing `TClientDataSet` `ApplyUpdates` calls when using the [SQLDirect components](http://www.sqldirect-soft.com/index.html) version 6.4.5

I made a small test app.
Components: `TDBGrid -> TDataSource -> TClientDataSet -> TDataSetProvider -> TSDQuery -> TSDDatabase`
Query is `select * from tt_plan_task`, Provider has `UpdateMode=upWhereAll`, ClientDataset has `IndexFieldName=tt_plan_task_id`.
We modify one value for field `tt_plan_task.tt_prj`.

When executing `ApplyUpdates(0)`, the code traces into `TSQLResolver.InternalDoUpdate` in `DataSnap.Provider` (for `UpdateKind=ukModify`).
There, the generated SQL and parameters look as expected.
The code then jumps to

```
procedure TSQLResolver.DoExecSQL(SQL: TStringList; Params: TParams);
var
  RowsAffected: Integer;
begin
  RowsAffected := (Provider.DataSet as IProviderSupportNG).PSExecuteStatement(SQL.Text, Params);
```

This statement crashes with error `SQL not supported` (SProviderSQLNotSupported in Data.DBConsts)

But since this an interface, I cannot trace further.
I don't know how to proceed from here in resolving the issue. **Any suggestions** how to, or what could be going on?

Additional info:

- Executing SELECT and (parameterized) UPDATE queries through a TSDQuery component work fine.
- Using a clientdataset with all FireDac components (`TDBGrid -> TDataSource -> TClientDataSet -> TDataSetProvider -> TFDQuery -> TDFConnection`) (different testapp) works fine
- This is a FireBird database with database dialect 3
- FireBird version is 2.5.3.26778
- Delphi 10 was installed without the Interbase components
- This is all in a Win7 VM where Delphi XE2 was removed from (everything 'Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero' cleaned out), and Seattle installed. My colleague has similar issues with a clean Seattle installation in a clean Win10 VM.
- Apps and FireBird are Win32, OSes are Win64

[*Note: self-answering this question because it took me quite some time to figure this out. It may help others*.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [Googling the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=tclientdataset+applyupdates+SQL+not+supported) I stumbled upon this post [SProviderSQLNotSupported on DOA with Delphi XE3](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=49345) where a user had similar issues with Oracle Direct Access.
 It suggests either:

1) Set `TDataSetProvider.ResolveToDataSet=true` at the cost of performance. This works in the test app.

2) The `PSExecuteStatement` may not be implemented (overridden) in the 3rd party software, and its base procedure from `data.db` kicks in:

```
function TDataSet.PSExecuteStatement(const ASQL: string; AParams: TParams): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  DatabaseError(SProviderSQLNotSupported, Self);
end;
```

That second situation is what happens. The SQLDirect code does have an override for the TSDDataSet method

```
function PSExecuteStatement(const ASQL: string; AParams: TParams; {$IFDEF SD_CLR} var ResultSet: TObject {$ELSE} {$IFDEF SD_VCL17} var ResultSet: TDataSet {$ELSE} ResultSet: TSDPtr = nil {$ENDIF} {$ENDIF}): Integer; overload; override;
```

which under Delphi Seattle resolves/compiles to override:

```
function PSExecuteStatement(const ASQL: string; AParams: TParams; var ResultSet: TDataSet): Integer; overload; override;
```

but there is none for

```
function TDataSet.PSExecuteStatement(const ASQL: string; AParams: TParams): Integer;
```

The solution is to add one:

In the protected methods for TSDDateSet in SDEngine.pas, update as follows:

```
function PSExecuteStatement(const ASQL: string; AParams: TParams): Integer; overload; override; // New override
function PSExecuteStatement(const ASQL: string; AParams: TParams; {$IFDEF SD_CLR} var ResultSet: TObject {$ELSE} {$IFDEF SD_VCL17} var ResultSet: TDataSet {$ELSE} ResultSet: TSDPtr = nil {$ENDIF} {$ENDIF}): Integer; overload; override;
```

with implementation:

```
function TSDDataSet.PSExecuteStatement(const ASQL: string; AParams: TParams): Integer;  // JD 20-4-2016
var
  ds: TDataSet;
begin
  ds := nil;
  Result := InternalPSExecuteStatement( ASQL, AParams, false, ds );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem migrading from Delphi 2009  to  Seattle 10, on `TAsaDataSet + TDataSetProvider + TClientDataSet` 
 we solved the problem  changing a few properties:

```
AsaDataSet.readyOnly := true;
DataSetProvider.ResolveToDataSet := True;
```

then at some point of our code we made sure the TAsaDataSet its able to its table.

```
TAsaDataSet .Close;
TAsaDataSet .Session  := DmConection.AsaConnection;
TAsaDataSet .SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM dba.table_name';
TAsaDataSet .Open;
```

We also notice from 2009 to Seatle the method signature `OnGetTableName` from:
`(Sender: TObject; DataSet: TDataSet; var TableName: WideString);` to:
`(Sender: TObject; DataSet: TDataSet; var TableName: string);`

Hope somehow it helps you.